# Getting day of date in filemtime with strftime

Tags: php, html, date, strftime

at the end of my webpage I want to display the date of the used xml-file. I do it with this code:

```
  <?php

          $html = "";

          $filename = '../XML-Daten/Wein.xml';

          $Speicherdatum = date('j. n. Y', filemtime($filename));

          setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE");

          $wochentag = strftime("%A",  $Speicherdatum);

          $jahr = date('Y');

          $html .="<div id='ca'>&copy; Company  1990 - $jahr<br />
          Aktualisiert: $wochentag, den $Speicherdatum</div>";

          echo $html;
```

?>

Now I get the right date ($Speicherdatum) but the day is always "thursday". Where is my error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of `strftime` expects an integer timestamp and not a formatted date string.

Try this instead:

```
$wochentag = strftime("%A", filemtime($filename));
```